# how to get current datetime in SQL?

Tags: sql, database, current-time

Want to get `current datetime` to insert into `lastModifiedTime` column. I am using **`MySQL`** database. My questions are:

1. is there a function available in SQL? or
2. it is implementation depended so each database has its own function for this?
3. what is the function available in MySQL?

Comment: Wouldn't it be nice if ANSI-SQL required that these basic system functions were named consistently across platforms? Standardize (substring or substr) or (IsNull or NVL).

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Complete answer:

**1. Is there a function available in SQL?**
Yes, the SQL 92 spec, Oct 97, pg. 171, section 6.16 specifies this functions:

```
CURRENT_TIME       Time of day at moment of evaluation
CURRENT_DATE       Date at moment of evaluation
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  Date & Time at moment of evaluation
```

**2. It is implementation depended so each database has its own function for this?**
Each database has its own implementations, but they have to implement the three function above if they comply with the SQL 92 specification (but depends on the version of the spec)

**3. What is the function available in MySQL?**

```
NOW() returns 2009-08-05 15:13:00  
CURDATE() returns 2009-08-05  
CURTIME() returns 15:13:00
```

Answer (score 12):

`NOW()` returns `2009-08-05 15:13:00`

`CURDATE()` returns `2009-08-05`

`CURTIME()` returns `15:13:00`

Answer (score 11):

I always just use NOW():

```
INSERT INTO table (lastModifiedTime) VALUES (NOW())
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now

Comment: this doesn't answer the question at all

Answer (score 11):

```
SYSDATETIME() 2007-04-30 13:10:02.0474381
SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()2007-04-30 13:10:02.0474381 -07:00
SYSUTCDATETIME() 2007-04-30 20:10:02.0474381
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 2007-04-30 13:10:02.047 +
GETDATE() 2007-04-30 13:10:02.047 
GETUTCDATE() 2007-04-30 20:10:02.047
```

I guess NOW() doesn't work sometime and gives error ***'NOW' is not a recognized built-in function name.***

Hope it helps!!! Thank You.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/getdate-transact-sql

Comment: *these are the functions you'd use in MS SQL Server

Answer (score 8):

I want my datetime, and I want it [now()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now)!

For MySQL, anyway.

Comment: That's cute... Doesn't work with Microsoft though: "I want my date, and I want it GetDate()!"

Comment: Sure it does. "Well, mister, you can just GetDate() yourself from now on!"

Answer (score 3):

1. `GETDATE()` or `GETUTCDATE()` are now superseded by the richer `SYSDATETIME`, `SYSUTCDATETIME`, and `SYSDATETIMEOFFSET` (in SQL 2008)
2. Yes, I don't think `ANSI` has ever declared anything, and so each manufacturer has their own.
3. That would be `NOW()`

Hope this helps...

Rob

Answer (score 3):

try this

`SELECT CURTIME();` return 23:12:58

`SELECT CURDATE();` return 2020-11-12

`SELECT NOW();`  return 2020-11-12 23:19:26

`SELECT DAY(now());`  return 12

`SELECT DAYNAME(now());`  return Thursday

Hope this would be helpful for you.

Answer (score 2):

For SQL Server use GetDate() or current_timestamp. You can format the result with the Convert(dataType,value,format). Tag your question with the correct Database Server.

Answer (score 2):

Just an add on for SQLite you can also use

```
CURRENT_TIME
CURRENT_DATE
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

for the current time, current date and current timestamp. 
You will get the same results as for SQL

[sql](/questions/tagged/sql) [sqlite](/questions/tagged/sqlite)