# Can I update current date automatically in SQL?

Tags: java, sql, date, current-time

I'm trying to save data in my table for these column: year, month and date respectively.
Is there a way to set these columns to adjust or update automatically to the current year, month and date?

Comment: Do you mean to make the date columns reflect the current date when you are inserting the record in Java?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233506/how-to-get-current-datetime-in-sql) . We usually use DB specific functions for this.

Comment: You shouldn’t store year, month and day of month separately in three columns. Make one column of type `date` and store your date there (nearly all RDBMSs have a `date` datatype for this purpose). And yes, then most RDBMSs also offer ways to update the column value automatically.

Comment: Why would you want to **store** the current date when that changes every 24 hours? Why don't you just include `current_date` (or the non-standard equivalent in your DBMS) in your SELECT statement?

Comment: Yeah i think i can just insert date column and extract whatever i need from that date. Thank you all for your comments and insights. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DATENAME` function in sql. e.g. `select DATENAME(year,getdate())`

Comment: There is no function `datename()` in (standard) SQL ("SQL" is a query language - not the name of a specific database product)